# Config Manager 2012 Application Download stuck at 0%

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, system-center, configuration-management

We have a Config Manager 2012 R2 setup with 2 Distribution Points on remote sites.
In the remote site the Applications don't get downloaded, the status remains on 'downloading (0% complete)'

In the DataTransferService log I find the following errors:

> Successfully sent location services HTTPS failure message.
>   Error sending DAV request. HTTP code 600, status ''
>
> GetDirectoryList_HTTP mapping original error 0x80072efd to 0x800704cf.
>
> GetDirectoryList_HTTP('https://DPSERVER.OURDOMAIN.com:443/NOCERT_SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/1f90ce9d-d4a0-44c4-a1af-7ece7b1c0ef6') failed with code 0x800704cf.
>
> Error retrieving manifest (0x800704cf).  Will attempt retry 9 in 3600 seconds.

I've disabled the Firewall on both the client and the DP. No change
The DP has a valid Web Server Certificate installed and the client has a valid workstation authentication certificate installed.
If I open a browser and navigate to https://DPSERVER.OURDOMAIN.com:443/NOCERT_SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/PIT00004 it displays a 'IE cannot display this page' error. If I open the 'http://'-version of the url it throws an '403 - Access Denied' errorr (which is correct).

I'm currently stuck with it. Any suggestions as to where to look for a resolution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved eventually. It turned out that no httpS listener was created by the DP installation process....

Answer (score 0):

You may check your IIS settings. Open the IIS managment console and goto application pools. Got to SMS Distribution points pool, right click and select advanced settings. make ***Enable 32-bit applications*** setting to be ***false***.